# How can I make a full backup of my system drive with Windows 7 and Ubuntu installed?

Tags: windows-7, backup, ubuntu-10.04, windows-backup

I have one 160GB and one 1TB hard drive.

On the 160GB drive I have Windows 7 and Ubuntu installed on the C: drive. On drive D: I have some programs installed.

I want to make a complete backup of both the drive (save disk image) to the second hard disk (1TB) so that if anything happens like a virus attack I can restore both Windows and Ubuntu 10.04 with the programs installed.

I want to know how to backup and restore this configuration without any issues, because I have never made a backup of the system drive before.

Are there are reliable freeware solutions available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Clonezilla Live](http://clonezilla.org/). Instructions: http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live-doc.php (you want `Save disk image`)

Comment: i have found full how to of clonezilla here http://www.howtoforge.com/back-up-restore-hard-drives-and-partitions-with-clonezilla-live

Comment: One of my favorite sites.